# Window keeps opening off screen, serious help needed

Tags: windows, windows-11

We have the issue where a window will just open outside of the clickable screen, every single time.

We tried:

- moving the windows with Win + Arrows
- closing with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Close
- restarting explorer
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
- using taskbar or taskmanager to restore or maximize the window
- changing the resolution and scaling

We managed it a few times to restart explorer and set a different resolution, each time the PC flickers and takes ages to probably show the desktop right and if we're lucky, a thin strip of the window, enough to grab it with the mouse, appears and we can drag it into the visible screen center. However, this is absolutely hit or miss and EVERY TIME we restart the program it starts off screen again.

We cannot access or mod registry to do this. This is a work PC and the program window with the issue is a Navision dynamics window that is not properly recognized as window that can be maximized (this is greyed out). The only solution would be if windows were nice enough to not open it outside of clickable area/save the position we painstakingly dragged it to to eventually see it. Even beyond several restarts, the PC remembers the wrong position.

Is there any way to fix this? It is unfortunately the Windows 11.

Comment: Do you by chance of a second monitor that is disconnected? What do your system administrator(s) have to say about the problem?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: There is only one minitor and we already swapped HDMI cables and ports in hopes to trigger a usable desktop/windows placement.

Comment: the company IT department cannot help with this. they tell us to restart and that moving windows around is not a support issue and they will not escalate my ticket elsewhere, they just close it again and again. of course I tried to see if the admin can help us